# TypeScript: How to infer the exact type of the assigned value

Tags: typescript

When you write this in typescript:

```
const x = 1;
```

x's type is inferred to be number. Can I make TypeScript infer this as the type `1`? (So it can only get assigned the value 1).

Likewise:

```
const x: {
  name: 'Name',
  age: 0,
}
```

I would like x's type to be inferred as:

```
{
   name: 'Name',
   age: 0,
}
```

I remembered I've seen some keyword that does it but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `x`, your assumption is incorrect

> x's type is inferred to be number

That would only the case if you had used the `let` keyword. Since you have used the `const` keyword, the variable can never be reassigned, so what you want to happen *already happens*.

`const x = 1` infers the type `1` not `number`.

For `y`, the way to achieve this is using [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

```
const y = {
   name: 'Name',
   age: 0,
} as const;
```

This creates an object that cannot be mutated; thus `y.name` has the type `'Name'` and `y.age` has the type `0`

Comment: Nice! Followup question: what if I want to do that but also enforce that my const is assignable to some defined type, for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIhwC2EAXMllKAOYDcBRcdEA-FSAK6kBG0JgF88eBAHsQWZAA8q6aQF5czQiXJUA5BgAWiPVE0AaPEORwMyCVLBMxkjOIA2EAHRPxdABQzXrCACUDMgA9CHIAJLIAO5w4MhgOsCWYOLI8MBOQA

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking... maybe raise this as a new question?

Answer (score 2):

Use [const contexts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const x = 1 as const;

const y = {
  name: 'Name',
  age: 0,
} as const
```